# swift2: set textview delegate is not work

Tags: ios, swift2

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let a = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 50))
        view.addSubview(a)
        a.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let b = c()
        a.delegate = b
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

class c:NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        print("A")
    }
}
```

textViewDidChange not work

Comment: Please clarify your question and which area you require help in. It would help you get more concise answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate is a weak reference. If you create the delegate object in `viewDidLoad`'s local scope it's gonna get deallocated. You need to save the delegate object to instance variable to keep the reference and the object in memory:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var b: C!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let a = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 50))
        view.addSubview(a)
        a.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.b = c()
        a.delegate = b
    }
    .....
}
```

Also, consider naming your variables to actually mean something. People won't be willing to help you if the code hurts to read.